# Passing value from image.onload to the surrounding function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload, onerror

I want to know if an image path exists, so I load the image with Javascript using `onload` and `onerror`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('image', function(submission_id, point_id) {
    var picture = new Image();

    picture.onload = function() {
        alert('test');
        result = '<img src="' + picture.src + '" />';
    };
    picture.onerror = function() {
        result = '0';
    };
    picture.src = 'static/uploads/submissions/' + submission_id + '/' + point_id + '.png';
    return result;
});
```

`Onload` and `onerror` is working because if the path is correct, I get the alert "test". But the problem is, returning of `result` doesn't work. I know, it doesn't work because `onload` is called asynchronously and fired after the returning of result. But how can I solve this?

Comment: I think you should take a step back here... What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to test if an image exists at a URL, and do different things depending on success or failure? How does Handlebars figure into this?

Comment: Yes I want to test if an image exists, because sometimes there is an image available and sometimes there is not. I use handlebars as template engine for showing informations about geographical points in a sidebar in leaflet.
So if the picture exists, I pass the image tag with the image to handlebars template. Because otherwise I would get an ugly 'no image' symbol if there is no picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the code is asynchronous, the return statement wont work. Instead what you need to do is define a function, (known as a callback) which is called when the image is loaded. Then your code would look something like this.

```
var picture = new Image();
picture.src = "something";
picture.onload = function() {
    callback(picture);
}
```

And then the callback would look like this.

```
var callback = function(picture) {
    doSomething(picture);
}
```

You can read more about callbacks [here](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know callbacks, but then I would have the problem that the returning function is not the original function.
The function is called by Handlebars template and expects the output as a return.
So I need a function that checks, if image exists and returns the image tag '<img scr"..." > if image and empty string or if the image doesn't exist.

Comment: I think, the only solution is adding the picture path to database if there is an pciture and include it in the already existing json file, istn't it? So I can check, if there is a picture path available or if it's empty.